# eclipse editor colors - how to set in outline view

Tags: eclipse, colors, setting

The line that is highlighted on Eclipse is really hard for me to see. I am color blind, but I can see colors.  I assume the the highlight color in the outline screen has very little contrast to the other colors.  Thank you!

Anyway I will try and attach a graphic.... anyone know to change this?[image]

Comment: The color seems to be inherited from the theme of the desktop environment of your operating system, at least that's the case on Gnome.

Comment: @free_easy is right, this is something that comes from your OS. It looks like you're on Windows. [This](http://superuser.com/questions/61821/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-highlighted-file-color-in-windows-7) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/59318/how-to-increase-contrast-of-windows-7-menu-item-highlight) is the closest I got to an answer - someone there suggested using a resource hacker to change the value in the DLL. I tried doing that myself but couldn't locate anything remotely like the highlight color. Maybe you'll have better luck!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have something usable enough to post as an answer. You didn't specify the OS that you're using but from the screenshot it looked like Windows 7/Vista with the Aero theme. Like I mentioned in my comment to your question, from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/61821/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-highlighted-file-color-in-windows-7) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/59318/how-to-increase-contrast-of-windows-7-menu-item-highlight), it looks like there isn't any [straightforward] way to change the highlight color.

However, if you don't mind losing the Aero effects, you can switch to the Windows Classic theme to get a different highlighting that IMO provides more contrast and better readability.

[image: Highlighting in Eclipse's Outline view on Windows 7 - Before (with Windows 7 (Aero) theme) and After (with Windows Classic theme)]